# Dynamic css on a parent window in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, dynamic-css

I like to add a dynamic css file to a **Parent** window.
I build this code for it:

```
function LoadJSCSSFile(filePath,fileType,parentBOO){
    //-
    var fileRef;            // Get the file reference
    //-
    //Set external JavaScript/CSS file
    switch(fileType){
        case "js":
            fileRef = document.createElement('script');
            fileRef.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            fileRef.setAttribute("src", filePath);
            break;
        case "css":
            fileRef = document.createElement("link");
            fileRef.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            fileRef.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
            fileRef.setAttribute("href", filePath);
            break;
        default:
            return;
            break;
    }

    //Load the file
    if(parentBOO){
        parent.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileRef);
    }else{
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileRef);
    }
}
```

Its working fine in FireFox and Chrome but in Internet Explorer 6,7 (i do not check in 8,9 yet) i am getting the next javascript error:
"Invalid argument"
On this line:

`parent.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileRef);`

I was wondering that it is because the cross domain security so i add this line
in the parent window:

`"document.domain = '127.0.0.1';"`

But its **not** help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The problem was that i create the element not on the same window object.
To fix it i add the line: parent.document.CreateElement instead of: document.CreateElement

The fixed code is:

```
function LoadJSCSSFile(filePath,fileType,parentBOO){
    //-
    var fileRef;            // Get the file reference
    //-
    //Set external JavaScript/CSS file
    switch(fileType){
        case "js":
            if(parentBOO){
                fileRef = parent.document.createElement('script');
            }else{
                fileRef = document.createElement('script');
            }
            fileRef.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            fileRef.setAttribute("src", filePath);
            break;
        case "css":
            if(parentBOO){
                fileRef = parent.document.createElement("link");
            }else{
                fileRef = document.createElement("link");
            }
            fileRef.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            fileRef.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
            fileRef.setAttribute("href", filePath);
            break;
        default:
            return;
            break;
    }

    //Load the file
    if(parentBOO){
        parent.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileRef);
    }else{
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileRef);
    }
}
```